# How to find index of a list in a new dataframe by mapping?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, mapping

I have a dataframe which contains list,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': [['hi', 'hello', 'bye'], ['school', 'pen'], ['hate', 'love', 'feelings', 'sad']]})


print(df)

    Item
0   [hi, hello, bye]
1   [school, pen]
2   [hate, love, feelings, sad]
```

Expected output:

```py
    mapped_value
0   [0, 1, 2]
1   [0, 1]
2   [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I tried using map(). I also used

```py
df['mapped value'] = [i for i, x in enumerate(df['Item'][0])]
df
```

which gives me the wrong output. I need the index for the whole list, but nothing works, can someone please guide?

Comment: In order to ask a question on stack overflow, you need to provide code demonstrating what you've tried and where you're stuck. See [ask].

Comment: that question had few mistakes, so i already removed it, and also for this query couldn't find much relevant resource, i already editted. so could you help me in this? Thank you so much :) @MichaelDelgado

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested list comprehension:

```
df['mapped value'] = [[i for i, x in enumerate(x)] for x in df['Item']]
```

Or lambda function:

```
df['mapped value'] = df['Item'].apply(lambda x: [i for i, x in enumerate(x)])
```